# Kendo ui Numeric with custom format from cents to Euros

Tags: jquery, formatting, kendo-ui, format, numeric

my backend sends a number like this: 250 (represents Euro, in cents)

Is it possible to formatting this with a custom format to "2,50 €"?

Using Knockout-Kendo.js databinding.

```
<input data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: myValue, format: 'c', culture: 'de-DE', step: 0.1 }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add a culture that uses the Euro currency (say Germany de-DE) and set the format to 'c' (You may have to handle the conversion from cents to dollars yourself).

```
$("#txtCurrencyEuro").kendoNumericTextBox({
  value: 250,
  culture: "de-DE",
  format: "c"
});
```

http://jsbin.com/UKowoHE/1/edit

Comment: Hm, thanks but not really helps ... Standard format and cuture is obvious to me. sorry.

Comment: I'm not great with knockout extenders, but I imagine something like http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html (Live Example 1: Forcing input to be numeric) might help

Answer (score 0):

The formatting for Germany de-DE is written 2,50 €. If you use for example en-IE (Ireland) the formatting will be what you are looking for €2.50.

Just to be clear for anyone else you must include the culture you require

```
<script src="../js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-IE.min.js"></script>
```

And then in your code:

```
kendo.culture("en-IE");
```

Hope this helps.